# ComboBox binding to enum, what did I do wrong?

Tags: wpf, enums, combobox

I have searched around and it seems very easy to bind enums to combobox, just retrieve Enum values as a list of strings via an ObjectDataProvider from the static Enum.GetValues method, however i can't get it to work.   The error is Type ContactExportType was not found.

I have an enum called ContactExportType, it resides on Enums class.  This class is part of the CEM.Marketing.Objects namespace.

This is what i have:

```
<UserControl 
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CEM.Marketing.Objects"
 xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<Grid>
<Grid.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
                    x:Key="ContactExportTypes">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:ContactExportType" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>

    </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Grid.Resources>

</Grid>
 <ComboBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding {StaticResource ContactExportTypes}}"
...
```

Thanks,
Angela

Comment: Thanks Chris for your help.  I couldn't do it in XAML after trying different things.  Seems like it does not support one level down in the class structure.  What I did to make it work is to bind the itemSource in code behind.

combobox.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof (Enums.ContactExportType));

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To access a nested type, you should use the "+" separator :

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
                    x:Key="ContactExportTypes">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="local:Enums+ContactExportType" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>

</ObjectDataProvider>
```

By the way, there is a simpler way to bind to the values of an enum, without using an ObjectDataProvider. It's based on a custom markup extension :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{local:EnumValues local:Enums+ContactExportType}"/>
```

Here is the code for the EnumValues markup extension :

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object[]))]
public class EnumValuesExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public EnumValuesExtension()
    {
    }

    public EnumValuesExtension(Type enumType)
    {
        this.EnumType = enumType;
    }

    [ConstructorArgument("enumType")]
    public Type EnumType { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (this.EnumType == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("The enum type is not set");
        return Enum.GetValues(this.EnumType);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you do this if your enum is not local?

Comment: @gonzobrains, what do you mean "not local" ? In the example above, `local` is just an XML namespace prefix mapped to the CLR namespace where the enum is defined. You can use any prefix and map it to any CLR namespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type local:Enums}"
                    x:Key="ContactExportTypes">
```

should be

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
                    x:Key="ContactExportTypes">
```

and

```
<x:Type TypeName="local:ContactExportType" />
```

should be

```
<x:Type TypeName="CEM.Marketing.Objects.ContactExportType"/>
```

the sys:Enum points to the Enum framework class
the typename in the parameter points to your fully qualified type-name.

check [Bea Stollnitz's blog](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=28)

```
    <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" x:Key="odp">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="namespace.class.TShirtSizes"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource odp}}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true"/>
```

Comment: If TShirtSizes is in different class and namespace, how do you specify it?  See my code...

Thanks,  Angela

Comment: you have to add an xmlns namespace to referance it---- xmlns:myenum="assembly;..."

Comment: your local xmlns is fine (assuming that is where you enum is at)

Comment: I changed ObjectType="{x:Type local:Enums}" to  ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}", still the same problem..

Comment: change your <x:Type TypeName="local:ContactExportType" /> to "CEM.Marketing.Objects.ContactExportType"

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response.  now i got an error: TyCEM.Marketing.Objects.ContactExportType' was not found..