# WPF Binding Enum to Command Parameters

Tags: wpf, enums, binding

I am trying to bind a Enum to CommandParameters of a button.  This cannot be static due to the fact that the button occurs in a ItemsControl.

Here is the Datatemplate:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameters="{Binding MyEnumParameter}" Text="{Binding MyText}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I am not sure what I need to do as the exception is Cannot convert enum to String.  My guess is I will need a ValueConverter for this please verify if that is the only route for this.

Comment: for anyone who is also trying to pass an enum as a command parameter [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359699/passing-an-enum-value-as-command-parameter-from-xaml) is SO post including several variations of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using a ValueConverter would be the right thing to do. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916278/wpf-binding-combobox-to-enum-with-a-twist) has en example you can use.