# Design time error while writing Nested type in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, nested

I have created a usercontrol which accept type of enum and assign the values of that enum to a ComboBox control in that usercontrol. Very Simple.
I am using this user control in DataTemplates. Problem comes when there comes nested type.
I assign that using this notation

> EnumType="{x:Type myNamespace:ParentType + NestedType}"

It works fine at runtime. but at design time it throws error saying

```
Could not create an instance of type 'TypeExtension'
```

Why?
Due to this I am not able to see my window at design time. Any help?

Comment: can you post a little bit mor code?

Comment: Is this in Visual Studio? Blend?

Comment: @AaronMcIver: this is in Visual Studio, I haven't checked with Blend.

Comment: @viky Added answer, issues/defect looks to be VS only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Rob Relyea](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/12f3e120-e217-4eee-ab49-490b70031806/) form Microsoft this is a defect within the VS2008/2010 designer.

> We had somebody look at the use of {x:Type Foo+Bar} pattern and test
>   it in VS2010 and Blend4. It appears that it works fine at Runtime,
>   CompileTime, in Blend 4, but fails in VS2010's WPF Designer.
>
> We've filed a bug, and routed it to the WPF Designer team.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220196/wpf-binding-a-combobox-to-an-enum-nested-in-a-class) You need to make use of the capabilities the `MarkupExtension` class provides.

however there is another way around it:

```
<ObjectDataProvider 
    MethodName="GetValues"
    ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
    x:Key="NestedEnumDataProvider">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="myNamespace:ParentType+NestedType"/>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```