# Reference nested enum type from XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

I can't seem to reference a public nested enum type from XAML.  I have a class

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
  public class MyClass
  {
    public enum MyEnum
    {
       A,
       B,
    }
  }
}
```

And I try to reference `MyEnum` in Xaml like this:

```
xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyApp"
....

{x:Type MyNamespace:MyClass:MyEnum}    // DOESN'T WORK
```

but VS complains it can't find public type `MyEnum`.  I also tried using the `+` syntax based on one of the answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676649/unable-to-find-enum-type-for-static-reference-in-wpf)...

```
{x:Type MyNamespace:MyClass+MyEnum}    // DOESN'T WORK
```

but that doesn't work either.

Note that `x:Static` *does* work with the `+` syntax:

```
{x:Static MyNamespace:MyClass+MyEnum.A}  // WORKS
```

And if I move `MyEnum` out of `MyClass` I can reference it too.  But not if it's nested...

So what am I missing?  How do I reference a nested enum from XAML using `x:Type`?  (And note, I'm not trying to instantiate anything, just reference the type).

**UPDATE**

It looks like this is just a bug with the VS 2010 designer.  The designer complains that `Type MyNamespace:MyClass+MyEnum was not found`.  But the application appears to run and properly access the nested type.  I tried this with a nested class too, and it works at run time.

Possible open bug: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/12f3e120-e217-4eee-ab49-490b70031806/

Related thread: [Design time error while writing Nested type in xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278925/wpf-design-time-error-while-writing-nested-type-in-xaml)

Comment: Looks like this might be a known bug in VS2010 designer?  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/12f3e120-e217-4eee-ab49-490b70031806/

Comment: In 2012 it works, altough Designer shows error until you build your project

Answer (score 3):

A bit late here, but I used a markup extension and then used the following references in my xaml to reference the nested enum in a combobox:

```
xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyApp"
```

...

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={resource:EnumBindingSource {x:Type MyNamespace:MyClass+MyEnum}}}"
```

The code for the MarkupExtension was taken from [here](https://brianlagunas.com/a-better-way-to-data-bind-enums-in-wpf/)

```
public class EnumBindingSourceExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private Type _enumType;
    public Type EnumType
    {
        get { return this._enumType; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._enumType)
            {
                if (null != value)
                {
                    Type enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(value) ?? value;
                    if (!enumType.IsEnum)
                        throw new ArgumentException("Type must be for an Enum.");
                }

                this._enumType = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public EnumBindingSourceExtension() { }

    public EnumBindingSourceExtension(Type enumType)
    {
        this.EnumType = enumType;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (null == this._enumType)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The EnumType must be specified.");

        Type actualEnumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(this._enumType) ?? this._enumType;
        Array enumValues = Enum.GetValues(actualEnumType);

        if (actualEnumType == this._enumType)
            return enumValues;

        Array tempArray = Array.CreateInstance(actualEnumType, enumValues.Length + 1);
        enumValues.CopyTo(tempArray, 1);
        return tempArray;
    }
}
```