# How to specify an enumeration in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, enums

My WPF application has an extension which I found in answer to a question on StackOverflow which creates choices for a `ComboBox` from an enumeration.  I don't remember which post I got it from, but as this isn't the problem, it's irrelevant.

I'm using a DLL for our product's backend in my WPF application.  There is an enumeration in this DLL that I want the user to pick from using a `ComboBox` and the afore mentioned extension.  I have the proper xmlns defined in the XAML.

The problem is that my enumeration is a subclass of another class.  That is, it's defined something like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    . . .

    public enum MyEnum { . . . }

    . . .
}
```

I thought that the XAML for the `ComboBox` should look something like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={cs:Enumeration {x:Type ns:MyClass.MyEnum}}}" 
          . . . />
```

As I type "MyClass", when I type the period to separate the parent class name from the subtype's name, Intellisense just provides the upper level class names again.  If I just type the subclass name after the period anyway, the compiler gives me an error: "Type MyClass.MyEnum not found".

How do I correctly specify the name of my enumeration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to punt on this and use the same mechanism that I use to load a `ComboBox` with choices pulled from a database.  That is:

1. I created an `ObservableCollection` in my view model class that holds the choices
2. I populate the `ObservableCollection` in the view model class' constructor with objects of a generic custom class called `ItemChoice`.  The declaration looks like:

   public ObservableCollection<ItemChoice<MyClass.MyEnum>> EnumChoices { get; set;
3. I bound the `ComboBox's ItemsSource` property to the `EnumChoices` collection in the XAML.
4. In the view model's constructor, I instantiate the `EnumChocies` collection and load it with new `ItemChoice` objects, one for each choice in the enumeration.

This all works.  I can move on to other problems with the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
{x:Type ns:MyClass+MyEnum}
```

http://neilmosafi.blogspot.co.uk/2007/08/dec-06-wpfxaml-xtype-and-nested-classes.html

Comment: This isn't working for me.  I'm using VS 2010 and I still get the "Type 'MyClass+MyEnum' not found" error.  The compiler is generating the error, so I can't run the executable, either.

Comment: @TonyVitabile: Looks like this was broken in VS2010. There's a workaround with a custom markup extension in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1220266/124386

Comment: I tried that workaround and it failed for me, too.  I keep getting the same error from the VS2010 compiler when I specify the `ns:MyClass.MyEnum` class name.

Comment: @TonyVitabile: I think you need to combine the two; use the `Type2Extension` from that answer with the `ns:MyClass+MyEnum` syntax.

Comment: That's what I did.  I added the `Type2Extension` to the code-behind for the window, then I used it and the `ns:MyClass+MyEnum` syntax in the XAML.  Same error.  I mistyped the previous comment

Comment: I believe the problem is that XAML doesn't support defining nested classes.