# Is it possible to Bind a ComboBox ItemsSource to a read only string[]?

Tags: wpf, combobox, bind, readonly, itemssource

I have a combo box in my WPF project and I would like to have it items defined by a readonly string array in my configuration class. This way I would make it very easy to reconfigure the combo box items.

Is it possible to bind my ItemsSource property to a readonly string[]? How it can be done?

Comment: It is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Sure I have tried, but I couldn't. That's why I would like some help here. Can you post the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MainWindow :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding List, Source={x:Static local:Configuration.Instance}}"></ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Configuration File :

```
public class Configuration
{

    // Singleton              
    private static Configuration _instance;
    public static Configuration Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new Configuration();

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> List
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<string>()
            {
                "toto 1",
                "toto 2"
            };
        }
    }

    public Configuration()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Binding to enum : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878356/wpf-combobox-binding-to-enum-what-did-i-do-wrong

Comment: can you do it without the singleton thing, e.g. if List is just a static property of Configuration?

Comment: @LouisRhys Maybe try something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3862828/1073409

Answer (score 3):

Yes, copy/paste/compile the following:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="Is it possible to Bind a ComboBox (WPF) ItemsSource to a read only string[]"/>
```